# For which areas of CAD and 2D/3D modeling and design is Blender a good choice?

Tags: modeling, vector

Blender is known for being a good product creating things like animations for videos. Is Blender also a good choice for other areas like:

1. 3D models for games
2. 3D models for 3D printing
3. 3D models for technical CAD like designing parts and plugging them together
4. mechanical respective kinetic simulation of moving parts
5. technical plans of buildings (in 2D and / or 3D)
6. 2D works in general like vector graphics

Did I miss a notable related area?

So this is a question asked to decide where to start diving into the CAD world. It would be nice if Blender could be used for all the above mentioned areas so that a newcomer does have to learn one tool only instead of several for different areas. The question may be naive because different areas need different tools, but all the areas have things in common, which I would say is working with vectors and therefore will have at least some tools in common.

Which of areas can be satisfied by Blender out of the box? Which can be satisfied by Blender with the use of plugins or extensions? For which should a newcomer better choose other tools? Proposals welcome. FLOSS preferred.

Comment: I would assert that blender can do all of the above, however you might find it easier to do 2D vector graphics in something like inkscape.

Comment: Blender is developed as a 3D creation suite for movies, and it can also make games content creation because the two are vaguely the same. But for the rest, it's not the best. CAD softwares and 2D graphics softwares are all different industries that each have different needs and almost developed each their own tools and technologies through time. While you can technically use Blender for typically CAD projects, it really isn't the tool made for that, you will hit limits, you will miss tools that are simple and thought for the task.

Comment: Think of it like using an 2D animator's drawing table to do an architect's job (or the other way around). Technically you can, because at the end of the day you can do "things" with just a pencil and a piece of paper. But the animators table have tools useless for architects, and miss all the rulers and GD&T tools and whatever an architect will need.